# iOS 13.4 simulator Capture Cursor issue

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator

Xcode 11.4 brought with it a totally new and powerful simulator with a separate toolbar, and this toolbar contains a few buttons and the first one is called `Capture Cursor`. But, unfortunately, it has some issues on my Macbook (with touch bar). 
When you click on this button you lose mac's cursor, and the iPad simulator gets all the focus (which is supposed). And to exit it, it says 'Press Esc to exit', but pressing Exit **does nothing** on my MacBook and I'm stuck in the simulator. Even more, **my touch-bar seems to freeze at all, and all the buttons stop responding**. 
So the question basically is, is this a known issue and how to fix it (get control back) without restarting mac by the press-and-holding power button?
[image]

Comment: Is it possible you're misunderstanding what that button does? You say: "When you click on this button you lose mac's cursor, and the iPad simulator gets all the focus." But isn't that exactly what's supposed to do? It is the same as IO -> Input -> Send Cursor to Device.

Comment: Yes, but there is no a way to get your cursor back! That's the point.

Comment: @matt Do you know a way how to Send the Cursor BACK to Mac?

Comment: This is not intended and so far we haven't been able to reproduce this behavior. As a workaround you can try using the Preferences window to change the shortcut to both Command keys (left and right command).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the easiest way is to just close and reopen the lid.

Comment: Thanks asking and answering! I was feeling kind of suffocated not knowing how to get out of this mode.

Comment: This isn’t really a valid solution, it would be good if you left this open as not everybody is on a MacBook with a lid!!

Comment: Update to Xcode 12 > Restart machine > Cmd button on touch bar becomes responsive

Answer (score 5):

Connecting another keyboard and pressing `ESC` on that one worked for me.

Comment: This helped me, thanks!  Pressing esc on my external keyboard was doing nothing, but it worked on the laptop's keyboard

Answer (score 4):

I had some success by plugging in a USB Keyboard (which was a pain bc I had to rummage for an adapter dongle too), and could use the escape key on that keyboard (I had to hold it for 3 seconds).

It seems that my Late 2016 MacBook Pro touchbar freezes entirely while the simulator captures my cursor.

Answer (score 4):

Triple clicking the touch ID button to open the accessibility option dialog, and clicking on `Keyboard Shortcuts` or `Preferences...` at the bottom of the dialog will escape from the simulator.

Answer (score 3):

The solution that works for Xcode 13.3.1 In the settings of Simulator just change the shortcut for stopping capture.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by:

1. Tap Touch ID
2. Switch User
3. Press ESC on Touch Bar to unfreeze the cursor
4. Login back with Touch ID

Answer (score 0):

After updating to `Xcode 12`, I got this issue for the first time only.
After `Force restart`, when I tried again, I'm able to switch back by tapping the `Command button on Touch Bar`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue on Xcode Version 12.0.1 (12A7300), MBP 2017. I had to force shut down to get back control of Mac.☹️

Also as mentioned by [@ramganghi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/900377/ramgandhi) in the comments above, the command button on Touch Bar became responsive after 1 force shout-down and re-starting the Mac.

Comment: Still present for Xcode 13.3.1

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me on Xcode 12. My Touch Bar becomes useless and unresponsive although it shows Esc, Command and other buttons. I tried all the solutions others suggested, and the ONLY think that worked for me is using the physical Esc button on my backup bluetooth keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to assign Escape action to Function (fn) key, then use fn key as a physical Esc key.

[image: assign fn key]

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was running a sysdiagnose

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command (⌘)</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

The screen will flash once and then after a couple of minutes a finder window pops up with the saved file.

At this point don't click back on the simulator to try and close it or it will all lock up again. Apple-alt-esc to force-quit the simulator worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Command Button in the Touch Bar releases the pointer from the simulator.